# Exporting Production SFDC Site.com and importing to Sandbox

Tags: community, force.com, force.com-sites, site.com, community-builder

After the Winter '16 upgrade, all of our Koa template modifications have been erased as described in the release notes.  Has anybody tried exporting their production site.com site and importing into a sandbox environment?

Typically a sandbox refresh would be ideal but in this case it does not work.  We are trying to test the upgrade from Community Koa Summer '15 to Winter '16 in our Sandbox  (Production Community is still on Summer '15).  The upgrade to Winter '16 wipes all the settings to the Koa template.  We are hoping to find a way to copy the Koa template settings from Production to Sandbox.  Refreshing the sandbox simply resets the Community Koa template to Summer '15 then the upgrade to Winter '16 deletes all the settings.